# ¿Mostrar un modal de bootstrap en Angular?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, modal, jhipster

**Contexto**

Estoy en aprendiendo angular y Jhipster, necesito mostrar un modal a modo mensaje de bienvenida al ingresar al sistema.

**El problema**

Mi modal no se muestra, solo se ve la sombra negra si que creo que estoy omitiendo algo pero no estoy seguro de que, la documentación es muy compleja y yo busco algo simple.

**Así luce mi componente HTML:**

```
<ng-template #modalMensaje let-modal>
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">
            <span>{{mensajeInicial.titulo}}</span>
        </h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="modal.dismiss('Cross click')">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p> <span>{{mensajeInicial.mensaje}}</span></p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="modal.close('Save click')">Save</button>

    </div>
</ng-template>
```

**y así luce mi componente ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import {ViewChild, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
import { IMensajeInicial } from 'app/shared/model/mensaje-inicial.model';
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
    selector: 'sigem-mensaje-inicial-detail',
    templateUrl: './mensaje-inicial-detail.component.html'
})
export class MensajeInicialDetailComponent implements OnInit {
    mensajeInicial: IMensajeInicial;
    @ViewChild("#modalMensaje") modal: ElementRef;

    constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private modalService: NgbModal) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe(({ mensajeInicial }) => {
            this.mensajeInicial = mensajeInicial;
            this.abrirModal(this.modal ,mensajeInicial);
        });
    }

    previousState() {
        window.history.back();
    }

    abrirModal(modal, mensajeInicial: any){
        this.mensajeInicial = mensajeInicial;
        this.modalService.open(modal);
    }

}
```

**y Así es como se ve ahora mismo:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Pregunta**

¿Cuál es la manera correcta de mostrar un modal mediante código del lado del componente ts?

**Notas**
Como notaron estoy aprendiendo no se estoy muy seguro de lo que estoy haciendo así que si me faltaron archivos o código para complementar la pregunta, por favor menciónenlo en los comentarios y completare la pregunta.

Comment: Puedes poner tu app.module.ts?

Comment: @Findelias creo que ya encontré el error era que puse un # en el @ViewChild("#modalMensaje")

Comment: Perfecto, pues apruebate tu respuesta como correcta cuando te deje y listo :)

Comment: @Findelias gracias 

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Después de analizar un poco más la documentación de Angular y TS descubrí mi error

```
 mensajeInicial: IMensajeInicial;
    @ViewChild("#modalMensaje") modal: ElementRef;
```

el `#`sale sobrando una vieja costumbre pues suelo programar en JQuery y que al parecer no es necesario en Angular para hacer referencia al ID

la manera correcta seria:

```
       @ViewChild('modalMensaje') modal: ElementRef;
```

Claramente un error de novato